# Перенаправление все ссылок с поддиректориями вида /folder1/folder2/../folderN/ в GET

Tags: .htaccess

Я написал собственный WEB файловый менеджер. Когда гуляю по папкам, то ссылка в адресной строке имеет такой вид:

```
https://site.com/folder1/folder2/folder3../
```

**Вопрос 1:** После обновления страницы я получаю 404, а мне необходимо, чтобы все запросы типа /folder1/folder2/folder3../ отправлялись в index.php

**Вопрос 2:** Можно ли как-то автоматически определять домашнюю директорию скрипта? Потому что если установить скрипт в подпапку `https://site.com/cms/`, то необходимо чтобы все запросы уже шли в index.php, но в подпапку с установленным скриптом /cms/.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Если нужно отдельный формат ссылок вида /downloads/$token/, то:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^download/([^/\.]+)/?$ dist/elements/connect.php?case=download_link&hash=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Как раз работает, если скрипт установлен даже в подкаталоги.